# Driver problems with NVidea Geforce GO 6600 on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, nvidia

I have install Ubuntu 12.04 in my computer and I want to Know, what is the best driver for the video card NVidia Geforce GO 6600?

Answer (score 0):

To install/Update Nvidia card drivers open Terminal.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below:

> ```
> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
> ```
>
> When installation complete restart your PC. Now to check the
>   installation is successful Press Window/Super key and type: nvidia x
>   server settings and open it.<sup>1</sup>

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Keep your Nvidia drivers up to date](http://www.noobslab.com/2011/09/nvidia-drivers-for-ubuntu-1110-oneiric.html)</sup>